# nginx - serve next js and wordpress site using same domain

Tags: wordpress, nginx, next.js

I have abc.com - next js application running using proxypass

there is wordpress project in same server. whenever there is request which has any param attached to it it should redirect to OR load content from wordpress folder.

Example:

abc.com - load next js app using proxypass
abc.com/:param - load content from wordpress

How can i setup this configuration using nginx?

Comment: Hi vaibhav and welcome here ! Would you provide us a full example of such a request and the complete final url you want to redirect to ? :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Philippe

i have one site : vaibhavportfolio.com

this site has home page build using next js and other inner pages build using wordpress

so when i hit vaibhavportfolio.com it should hit next js application using proxy pass
when i hit vaibhavportfolio/contact-us, vaibhavportfolio/about-us etc... it should load content from wordpress